# How to create a new button style?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Hello so I use a lot of button and I don't like the "animation" when my mouse is over the button so I found this :

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style 
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter 
            Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter 
            Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter 
            Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate 
                    TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border 
                        x:Name="border" 
                        BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                        BorderThickness="3" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        CornerRadius="0" 
                        Padding="0">
                        <ContentPresenter 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger 
                            Property="IsMouseOver" 
                            Value="True">
                            <Setter 
                                Property="BorderBrush" 
                                TargetName="border" 
                                Value="#252525"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

It works great, so I was wondering how to create a new Style named "NoMouseOver" that I can just choose here : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/42/1477013610-style.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could have find the answer to your question on a quick search (here on stackoverflow or google), here is a simple answer to your question:

Create the style in the Resources-section of your Window/UserControl:

```
<Windows.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NoMouseOverStyle" TargetType="Button">
        ...
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Afterwards you can select this style in the properties, or directly use it in your XAML.

```
<Button Style={StaticResource NoMouseOverStyle} />
```

Keep in mind that if you want to use this style in different windows or user controls, you may want to use ResourceDictionarys.

**EDIT**
As Steffen said, i removed the DynamicResource and replaced it with StaticResource.

Answer (score 0):

previous answer is correct, but i would use StaticResource instead DynamicResource for performance reasons.

Regards

Steffen

Comment: is this a answer or comment? seems to be a comment